# How to get marker position in google map

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have seen solutions including using `onDragEnd` or this method

```
void _updatePosition(CameraPosition _position) {
    Position newMarkerPosition = Position(
        latitude: _position.target.latitude,
        longitude: _position.target.longitude);
    Marker marker = markers["1"];

    setState(() {
      markers["1"] = marker.copyWith(
          positionParam: LatLng(newMarkerPosition.latitude, newMarkerPosition.longitude));
    });
  }
```

it shows on class `Position` : `Undefined class 'Position'`,
and `onDragEnd` not available

What is the reason and how can I get position from marker ?

Answer (score 0):

If the IDE/Flutter says "Position" is "Undefined", Please check you have imported the "Geolocator" package.  It's implemented in this package.

Add this to `pubspec.yaml` dependecies:

```
geolocator: ^6.1.7
```

and make sure it is imported in the .dart file you're working on. :)